# How can I pass a variable as a value in an API.. Im using Geocoding API. But i can't get the location

Tags: java, android, rest, google-maps

```
double lat = 13.630754;
double longi = 123.18484;
JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
  // Here is where i used the variables for latitude and longitude
String.format(" https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=",lat,",",longi,"&key=my key"),
                    new JSONObject(jsonParams),

                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //                              t.setText(response.toString());
                            String address = null;
                            try {
                                address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            t.setText(address);
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: You need to add ')' to close "JsonObjectRequest("

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.format(" https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=",lat,",",longi,"&key=my key")`

does not make any sense.

Either use string concatenation

`"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + longi + "&key=my key"`

or a proper format string

`String.format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%1$s,%2$s&key=my key", lat, longi )`

See the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: Yes Sir!! I got It now.. I used simple the "+" to add variables within the string,, It Works now!!              String location = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+longi+"&key=my key";

                JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.POST,

                        location,

                        new JSONObject(jsonParams),